# SQL boolean EXISTS while using aggregate function

Tags: sql-server

I have written a query that returns the list of all customers that have ever made a purchase with the company I work for. The person for whom I am getting the data would like to know if a specific criteria is true for any of these orders.

```
 select L.ParentLocation, 
 [Number of Orders] = count(distinct(T.Order))
 from Table1 L
 join Table2 T
 on L.Location = T.Location
 group by L.ParentLocation
```

However, the issue is complicated because I am already grouping by ParentLocation, and each ParentLocation has many normal Locations. So I am counting the number of unique orders at the location level, then grouping them by the ParentLocation.

I want to return 'TRUE' in the query if a field 'OrderDesc' contains "Toys" in ANY of the orders by ANY of the Locations owned by a ParentLocation. Is there a way to do this?

NOTE: Table2 contains the OrderDesc column.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    L.ParentLocation, 
    [Number of Orders] = count(distinct(T.Order)),
    has_toys = max(case when t.OrderDesc like '%toys%' then 'TRUE' else '' end)
from Table1 L
inner join Table2 T
   on L.Location = T.Location
group by
      L.ParentLocation
```